# Button onClick triggered when init in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu but I have some problems with onClick event on list items which are in child component, the 'handleClick' function is suppose to trigger when click on a list item, but the function is trigged twice when page loaded (because there are two lists here), and when I click on list again, it will trigger twice again, I'm sure it's a simple question but I passed few hours on it but I don't really understand what it happen here, hope someone can help me please, thx!

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropdown from './../elements/dropdown.js!jsx';

export class TestPage extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.noteLIst = [
      {name: 'note', label: 'Note global'},
      {name: 'digitalCulture', label: 'Digital Culture'}
    ];
  }

  handleItemClick(company) {
    console.log(company);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="widget">
        <Dropdown list={this.noteLIst} selected={this.noteLIst[0]} whenItemClicked={this.handleItemClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Dropdown.js

```
import React from 'react';

export class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      listVisible: false
    };
  }

  showMenu() {
    this.setState({
      listVisible: true
    });
    document.addEventListener("click", this.hide);
  }

  hide() {
    this.setState({
      listVisible: false
    });
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide);
  }

  handleClick(item) {
    console.log(item); // Here will log 2 items
    this.props.whenItemClicked(item);
  }

  render() {
    let listItems = _.map(this.props.list, (list, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index} className={list} onClick={this.handleClick(list)}>{list.name}</li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className = {"dropdown-container" + (this.state.listVisible ? " show" : "")}>
        <div className = {"dropdown-display" + (this.state.listVisible ? " clicked" : "")} onClick = {this.show}>
          <span>
            <img className="icon-arrow-bottom" src="build/image/arrow_bottom_black.png" />
          </span>
          <span>
            {this.props.selected.name}
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul className="dropdown-list" >
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use the onClick event and you want to pass parameters to the handler method, you have to use the function `bind`. Thus, the handler will be triggered only when you click on the list item.

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, list)}
```

This would be your Dropdown.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      listVisible: false
    };
  }

  showMenu() {
    this.setState({
      listVisible: true
    });
    document.addEventListener("click", this.hide);
  }

  hide() {
    this.setState({
      listVisible: false
    });
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide);
  }

  handleClick(item) {
    console.log(item); // it will be log 1 item when you click
    this.props.whenItemClicked(item);
  }

  render() {
    let listItems = _.map(this.props.list, (list, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index} className={list} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, list)}>{list.name}</li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className = {"dropdown-container" + (this.state.listVisible ? " show" : "")}>
        <div className = {"dropdown-display" + (this.state.listVisible ? " clicked" : "")} onClick = {this.show}>
          <span>
            <img className="icon-arrow-bottom" src="build/image/arrow_bottom_black.png" />
          </span>
          <span>
            {this.props.selected.name}
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul className="dropdown-list" >
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer works, but an explanation on the idea of bind would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that this works even when the function does not belong to `this`! Example:

config/GetFireBaseConfigFromEnv.ts

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";
import { FirebaseOptions } from "firebase/app";

const GetFireBaseConfigFromEnv = (): => {
  dotenv.config({path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../.env.development")});

  const config: FirebaseOptions = {
      apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
      appId: process.env.APP_ID,
      authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
      measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET
  };

  return config;
}

export default GetFireBaseConfigFromEnv;
```

auth/SignInWithGoogle.ts

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, Auth, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

const SignInWithGoogle = (auth: Auth): void => {
  const provider: GoogleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider(auth);
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
}

export default SignInWithGoogle;
```

components/app.ts

```
import React, { JSX } from "react";
import GetFireBaseConfigFromEnv from "config/GetFireBaseConfigFromEnv";
import SignInWithGoogle from "auth/SignInWithGoogle";

const App: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <button onClick={SignInWithGoogle.bind(this, GetFireBaseConfigFromEnv())}
          value="Login with Google"/>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work it out easily with functional components, since the class components became almost deprecated as of React v16, call the handler function from the body of an arrow function. I called the handler function (handleSearch) from inside a new arrow function because my handler function was an async function which returns a result so it was being called on every component render rather than on click event.

```
    <button style={{height:'55px'}} onClick={ () => {
          handleSearch(search, fetchData, exerciseOptions, setSearch, setSearchedExercises, setShowHeaderTitle, setBodyPart)}}>
            Search
</button>
```